# Does YugaByte plan to be one Pluggable Storage for PostgreSQL 12+?

Tags: database, postgresql, yugabytedb

I am new to YugaByte, but impressed by the things I have read about it so far.

One thing which might be beneficial for both YugaByte and Postgres community is to use YugaByte as one of the Pluggable Storages for PostgreSQL (>= version 12), thus taking advantage of this API and potentially making even more PG extensions work with YugaByte.

I am not sure if my understanding is correct, but if this integration is possible, I think it would make YugaByte even more interesting for large organizations.

Comment: You'd best ask the vendor. How should anybody else know their intentions?

Comment: Thanks! YugaByte is an Open Source Software, I was wondering that maybe someone from the community follows this forum and would be able to give some clue. You might be right though, it's probably better to ask this kind of question on their GitHub page. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in YugabyteDB! We did explore making it a Pluggable Store for PostgreSQL, however we found that this might not work because of the following points:

- YugabyteDB replicates the system catalog as well, which is not pluggable in PostgreSQL. Without making this change, the system catalog will become a single point of failure.
- We've had to change some internal workings given the data could be on a remote node, and therefore the change needed to be made at a layer higher than where the pure pluggable storage would live.

There are probably other reasons as well. But we're interested in making this possible over the long term, if its possible to provide enough "hooks" into PostgreSQL. For now, we plan to pull in newer PostgreSQL features as needed.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer makes a lot of sense. I hope both YugaByte and PG community eventually work together and bring this integration to reality.